# How to link to Google Scholar citations

Tags: href, http-status-code-403, citations, google-scholar

I am trying to develop a widget that would add to the depth of data available on a web page displaying academics' publications. One way I thought to achieve this was to provide some integration with google scholar for the sake of citations. Google scholar does not provide a mechanic for direct links to search results, but it does provide URLS for citations (be they in the form of BibTex, EndNote, or whatever).

These would be in a form like

https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:KVYNuhcDObAJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgVAf8hVELDk2K9LLoQ:AAGBfm0AAAAAZA9NNoRl5fNdfRGIyOANTvDy-fjNukRX&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAZA9NNlPScRvPBKBNm_4YSzOe4ldXgPHA&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en

I have consequently spent several hours putting together direct links to these citation forms and embedding these links in buttons beside the academics' paper listings.

All seemed well, until I found to my displeasure that these links seem to expire after about quarter of an hour, after which they generate a 403 forbidden error when used.

I could download all of the relevant information (to do with BibTex, EndNote, etc.) and upload that separately to a domain I control, and then link to that, but this is very sub-optimal as it would not take any changes into account that may occur to citation data stored on Google Scholar (which, while infrequent, does sometimes happen).

As such my question is whether there is any way to directly link to Google Scholar information on a permanent basis, or if not, is there another workaround for directly obtaining this data (there is no obvious API for generating citation data)